# Intensity of light through medium of glass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, polarization

I'm stuck in this following question: **Calculate I2 when incident light (Ii) is unpolarized.**

Values:

`01 = 0°` and `Ii = 625 W/m^2`

[image]

Comment: This kind of homework-like questions do not conform with SE. Please check out https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intensity of unpolarised light halves every time it passes through a polariser.